# Problema con JSON INVALID en DATA

Tags: php, datatables, pdo

Estoy intentando cargar una tabla con **DATATABLE** de la siguiente manera

```
$('#tabla_listado_pagos').DataTable({
    ajax:{
        url: '../models/listar_pagos.php',
        data: {
            numero_subcredito: 'TP108786',
        },
        method: 'POST'
    }
});
```

Todo cargar correctamente de la información de los registros de la consulta () mi problema es que la información la retorno como verán a continuación en el script listar_pagos.php

```
try {
    $sentenciaPreparada = $conexionBaseDatos -> prepare(
        "SELECT * FROM bujic_payboard.pagos WHERE registroAgente = :registroAgente AND 
        fechaPago BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 DAY) AND NOW() ORDER BY fechaPago 
        DESC"
    );
    $sentenciaPreparada -> bindValue(':registroAgente', $usuarioLogueado, 
    PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sentenciaPreparada -> execute();
    $listadoPagos['data'] = [];
    while ($pagos = $sentenciaPreparada -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $listadoPagos['data'][] = $pagos;
    }
    echo json_encode($listadoPagos);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $error = $e -> getMessage();
    echo "Ocurrió un problema al consultar y listar la información del titular, 
    error: $error";
}
```

Bien, hasta ahí todo bien, funcionando como "debería", sin embargo:

1. La DATA **numero_subcredito: 'TP108786'**, que mando desde la peticón de AJAX hacía listar_pagos.php realmente no la ocupo en el script, pero si la quita deja de funcionar, ¿Cuál es la manera de generar la petición sin mandar DATA? estaba viendo que hay algo conocido como "processing", "serverSide" y "dataSRC" pero no se como aplique o si aplica.
2. En caso de que no regrese ningún registro la consulta en el script, DATATABLE me indica error con INVALID JSON, quiero suponer que porque no regresa nada obviamente, ahí me imagino se hace una validación si regreso algo pero... ¿Es en lado del script PHP o de lado de DATATABLE?

¿Me pueden hechar una mano con ello?

Comment: Sobre tu punto 1) ¿que es `deja de funcionar`? ¿no muestra ningún error ni en la consola?... Sobre tu punto 2) Supongo que es porque entra en el `catch` y los datos no los envias en formato JSON.

Comment: 1.- Me marca invalid JSON en un alert (parte de DATATABLES) es porque no retorna nada en el JSON lo que no entiendo es como pedir la petición para que retorne el JSON, solo usando la URL

Comment: 2.- Usuarios que no tengan registros hacen que el JSON retorne vacío y por ende me da el error de invalid JSON y no carga la tabla, cosa que es normal que no cargue porque no retorna nada, ¿Pero como evito que me marque el error?

Comment: Supogo que DataTable tiene manejo de errores ¿no? Es decir, ha definido un tipo de objeto para para cuando no se deban mostrar datos en la tabla. Pues bien, en el código PHP debes controlar el flujo del código, produciendo un objeto según la convención de DataTable. Supongamos que sea algo así en caso de error: `{"error" : "No hay datos"}`, puedes en la parte de error de tu código (el `catch` por ejemplo), retornar esto: `echo json_encode(array('error'=>'No hay datos'));` En conclusión: acopla tu código a la convención de manejo de error definida por DataTable.